# document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'none', Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am importing a SVG as a react component (`Dog1`), some elements in the SVG need to be hidden so in order to do this i use `document.getElementById('id').style.display = 'none'` for all the ids of the elements that need to be hidden. This works some of the time and seems to be random if the SVG will load correctly on my react page. Sometimes it doesnt work and gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`.

I think this is probably because the `document` is actually getting the whole page opposed to just the SVG component, is there anyway i can fix this so that i get the SVG component?

my code is below (the forloops are used as a way to get multiple ids and set to none)

```
import { ReactComponent as Dog1 } from '../images/dog-chart-treatments.svg'


function NewChart() {

  function svgDog(Dog1){
    console.log(Dog1)
    console.log(document.getElementById("treatment-tooth-408"))

    for (let i = 401; i< 410; i++) {
      var fourZeroValue = `treatment-tooth-{}`.replace(/{}/, i)
      console.log(fourZeroValue, document.getElementById(fourZeroValue))
      document.getElementById(fourZeroValue).style.display = 'none'
    }
    for (let i = 101; i< 110; i++) {
      var oneZeroValue = `treatment-tooth-{}`.replace(/{}/, i)
      document.getElementById(oneZeroValue).style.display = 'none'
    }
    for (let i = 301; i< 310; i++) {
      var threeZeroValue = `treatment-tooth-{}`.replace(/{}/, i)
      document.getElementById(threeZeroValue).style.display = 'none'
    }
    for (let i = 201; i< 210; i++) {
      var twoZeroValue = `treatment-tooth-{}`.replace(/{}/, i)
      document.getElementById(twoZeroValue).style.display = 'none'
    }

  }

  svgDog(Dog1) 

    return (<div>


        <h1>Big Dog test</h1>
        <div className='displayChart'>
          <h4>Dog</h4>
          <hr></hr>
          <div className='image-gray'>
            <Dog1></Dog1>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        </div>

        
   
    );
  }
  
  export default NewChart;
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're calling the function svgDog before the SVG is rendered for the first time, which means the elements you're trying to access / hide don't exist yet.

Comment: So how should i call `svgDog` to prevent this?

Comment: The specific reason for the error is `document.getElementById('id')` being `null`, which points you to the root cause. The next step is to google "react run code after first render" which will point you to lots of existing solutions.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to use direct DOM access instead of generating the result you want with JSX directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling document.getElementById() the elements you are trying to find aren't rendered yet, try to use "useEffect"

Code inside this hook will run only when finished rendering

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Because this website isn't a casual chat forum, and this answer is not sufficient in multiple ways. For one, linking to the docs is pointless. If the answer is in the docs, neither the question nor the answer should be on this website in the first place. Plus, this is 100% a duplicate.

Comment: i am wondering the same...

Comment: @ChrisG well I'm sorry we had the same conclusions, I don't refresh the page constantly on my second monitor while answering. Although the question might've been answerable with the docs that doesn't change if my answer was useful and it wasn't a 100% duplicate. You pointed out the cause of the error I pointed out the cause and gave a fix.

Comment: ? I'm not here for rep and I didn't post an answer. Also, this is most definitely a duplicate. And the approach is questionable in the first place, which means taking the question at face value is bad if other people find it. Answers (and questions) are supposed to be useful for future readers. None of this is.

Comment: I'm just trying to tell you how this website works (or at least, how it's supposed to work). Don't take it personal.

Comment: @ChrisG well you could've told him that the question was invalid before answering it yourself. Also I believe it answered his question and I cannot comment due to low rep. Thats why I answered directly.

Comment: In some cases manipulating the DOM is the only way to fix something, I'm unsure if this can be solved within react.

Comment: Posting a comment as answer because of not enough rep means you deliberately violated the rules :) Anyway, yes, that's what the useRef hook is for. Using `document.*` methods in React is an absolute last resort, which is one more reason why I downvoted your answer.

Comment: As i said, i believe i answered his question and even if I wanted to comment my answer i couldn't. I don't think you can add a useRef to child elements of an SVG in this case so I assumed this is the only way to fix it. You can just add to my answer if you feel like it isn't complete but if you hover over the downvote button it says (this answer is not useful) which is not true.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I actually have made a solution to my 2 day-old problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

First assign it using variable:

```
let element1 = document.getElementById('id')
```

Next, check for it:

```
if (element1) {
   element1.style.display = "none"
}
```